# Build Errors in Unity : Failed to re-package resources

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build, apk

I am trying to build an APK in Unity 2017. But, I get these build errors below. Please let me know how to fix them. Thanks.

Below, I will post 2 groups of errors. The first one is what I get when I run the command "grep error Editor.log" on a terminal. The second one displays the errors shown in Unity console

(1) Errors seen after running the command "grep error Editor.log"

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_menu.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker'

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_song_list.xml:8: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'popupTheme' in package 'com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker'

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_song_list.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@StyLe/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar').

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_song_list.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'popupTheme' with value '@StyLe/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light').

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/search_view.xml:34: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker'

at UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_menu.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker'

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_song_list.xml:8: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'popupTheme' in package 'com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker'

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_song_list.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@StyLe/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar').

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_song_list.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'popupTheme' with value '@StyLe/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light').

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/search_view.xml:34: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker'

at UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors

Request timed out while processing request "https://core.cloud.unity3d.com/api/login", HTTP error code 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

Done fixing - no errors

Done fixing - no errors

*** ec1fcc9d3f841409d9b5eab910699049 replaces d6275b61db7054bf986a7e07bdc2288c at path assets/easymobile/scripts/native/ios/foundation/nserror.cs

Done fixing - no errors

AndroidManifest.xml:74: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@StyLe/MusicTheme').

at UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg) [0x00000] in :0

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors

Request timed out while processing request "https://core.cloud.unity3d.com/api/users/me", HTTP error code 0

An error occurred while processing request "https://core.cloud.unity3d.com/api/orgs", HTTP error code 299

.[UnityConnect] An error occurred.

---

(2) ERRORS  SHOWN in Unity console:

CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
/Users/thanh/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "/Users/thanh/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage:com.android.vending.billing:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:android.arch.lifecycle:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable:com.sglib.easymobile.androidnative:com.unity.purchasing:net.ktnt.musicdialog:com.unity.udp.sdk:com.unity.udp.udpsandbox:com.unity3d.ads:com.unity.udp.sdk.common -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/CropLib/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GoogleAIDL/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GooglePlay/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.sglib.easymobile.easy-mobile-1.1.0/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/common/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/udpsandbox/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unity-ads/res" -S "/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/utils/res"

stderr[
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:scrollIndicators from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:26: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:36: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml:24: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout for configuration v17.

/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml:59: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_select_dialog_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0/res/layout/abc_select_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/abc_select_dialog_material for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_menu.xml:41: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_menu.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_menu.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/activity_menu for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_song_list.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/songpicker/res/layout/activity_song_list.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/activity_song_list for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_action.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_action.xml:32: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_action.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/notification_action for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_action_tombstone.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_action_tombstone.xml:37: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_action_tombstone.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/notification_action_tombstone for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.astricstore.imageandvideopicker:layout/notification_template_big_media for configuration v17.
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:89: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:56: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit - May 2018 - Unity 2017/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from 
/Users/thanh/Unity - Homework/Flight Kit -

Comment: The error is everything after `stderr[` which unfortunately is the part you cut off before the error was printed.

Comment: I have updated the questions to report 2 groups of error messages. The first one is what I get when I run the command "grep error Editor.log" on a terminal. The second one displays the errors shown in Unity console. (Thanks).